# Why does taking sizeof(array) give warnings in a function, but not in main()?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm currently coding some encryption algorithm, and I am facing a GCC compilation error I can't understand. Here is the problem :

In my `int main(void)` function I got :

```
uint32_t block[2];
memset(block, 0x0, sizeof(block));
printf("%ld \n", sizeof(block));
```

Which looks okay for GCC.

Then, I pass this uint32_t array named `block` to a function :

```
void readOneBlockFromFile(int fd, uint32_t block[2]){
  if(fd == -1){
    perror("fd");
    errno = EIO;
    exit(errno);
  }
  int nb_bytes_read = 0;
  while(1){
    memset(block, 0x0, sizeof(block));
    nb_bytes_read = read(fd, block, sizeof(block));
    if(nb_bytes_read == -1){
      perror("read");
      exit(errno);
    }
    if(nb_bytes_read == 0){
      break; //EOF
    }
  }
}
```

And here I get some GCC warnings :

```
SPN.c: In function ‘readOneBlockFromFile’:
SPN.c:46:30: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘block’ will return size of ‘uint32_t * {aka unsigned int *}’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
     memset(block, 0x0, sizeof(block));
                              ^
SPN.c:38:44: note: declared here
 void readOneBlockFromFile(int fd, uint32_t block[2]){
                                            ^~~~~
SPN.c:47:43: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘block’ will return size of ‘uint32_t * {aka unsigned int *}’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
     nb_bytes_read = read(fd, block, sizeof(block));
                                           ^
SPN.c:38:44: note: declared here
 void readOneBlockFromFile(int fd, uint32_t block[2]){
                                            ^~~~~
```

So my GCC is giving me warning when I'm using `block` without using `block[0]` or `*block`.

I can't figure out why GCC gives me warning for this, as I can do the same stuff without any problem in main.

Comment: You don't have an array inside your function. I can't see how much more informative can that warning be.

Comment: When you attempt to create an array parameter, it always becomes a pointer.

Comment: That's because arrays are passed by reference in C, not by value.

Comment: Isn't `uint32_t block[2]` and array?

Comment: It may *look* like an array, but it isn't.

Comment: @Nofix Not if it's a parameter.

Comment: Not in a function parameter list it isn't. You need to get back to C basics.

Comment: So do you have any idea about how I could use my sizeof(block) without warnings, and have the result I expect to have? (I want sizeof(block) to return 8, as my block array is 2 cells of uint32_t)

Comment: Pass length as a separate parameter.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for those informations !

Comment: Also, keep in mind that unless you add `@username` to your messages, those you reply to won't get notifications (unless the comment is under their post or nobody else had commented under a post) and might not reply.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat didn't knew that, thanks. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Cool warning, BTW. Since when does GCC issue this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function heading

```
void readOneBlockFromFile(int fd, uint32_t block[2])
```

you declare `block` to be an array of size 2. However, in C an array is *always* pased as a pointer to its first element. Therefore `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer, not of the array.

(In essence, declaring the size of an array you pass helps the compiler check your code, whether you pass the right arguments. In multi-demensional arrays the compiler lets you use `[][]` indexing. Without declaring the size of the array passed, that would not be possible.)

You further seem to know already what size the array is, so pass that to `read`, e.g. `sizeof(uint32_t [2])`.

---

In my opinion a more usefull interface is:

```
int readOneBlockFromFile(int fd, void *block, int size)
{
     int nb_bytes_read = read(fd, block, size);
     //...
     return nb_bytes_read;
}
int example(void)
{
    uint32_t block[2];
    if (readOneBlockFromFile(1,block,sizeof(block))==0) {
        // EOF
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To support Paul Ogilive's awesome answer:

From C11 standard [6.3.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1)

> *Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue.* If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

This is the exhaustive rule - in case when array is converted into pointer and when it is not. Here it is also a case where array is converted into pointer when it is passed to a function.

*-Emphasis mine*